# Restkit cannot read valid json?

Tags: ios, json, restkit

am just starting off with restkit for ios. I have a very simple json response

{
    "result": [
        {
            "userid": "5964",
            "name": "Your Name"
        }
    ]
}

This is a valid json (tested against jsonlint)

However, when i try to use this with RKClient, it doe'snt see it as json. This is my code

```
-(void) request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response{

    if([request isGET]){
        if([response isJSON]){
            NSLog(@"JSON Response from Server %@", [response bodyAsString] );    
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Non JSON Response from Server %@", [response bodyAsString] );    
        }
    }

}
```

It always logs "Non JSON Reponse...." but the json is perfectly valid. The same thing happens when i use RKObjectMapping; the error will be "Unable to find parser for MIME Type text/xml.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to parse JSON and you have error "Unable to find parser for MIME Type text/xml", your problem is probably in header in your restkit config or in your serveur response.
Restkit : [RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
Serveur response header should be "application/json", and not "text/xml". Do you have logs serveur side ?

Comment: Thaks Beber, I have set [RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; That did'nt work. However, things seemed good once i added headers to the server script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit dumb, but things got solved once i added

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to the server script.

Answer (score 9):

If for any reason you can't change the server headers and returned Mime type to xml or json, you can still add mapping for mime type 'text/html' to be processed as json.

Just add :

```
[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] setParserClass:[RKJSONParserJSONKit class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
```

And don't forget to add the related header file :

```
#import <RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>
```

Works for me.

Have a look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-a-Custom-MIME-Type

Comment: Works for me too! It was the only answer I could find that really did the work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Serveur response header should be "application/json", and not "text/xml". ;p